Plotting a graph with wide range of numbers
I would like to plot two columns of a dataframe against one column. The values in these columns are a wide range of numbers.
data = {'A': [ -0.9, -0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9,], 
        'B': [0, 0, 17, 59, 243, 6777, 35531, 909876, 3, 8],
        'C': [7312, 22434, 10787, 4576, 25,  0, 5, 12, 0, 32]} 

[I have put the numbers are in an order in the example, to show that the values of B against the values of A vs the values of C against the values of C, but they need not be.]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.plot(x='A', y='B', kind='line')
df.plot(x='A', y='C', kind='line')

Since the range of numbers is large, I cannot see the smaller numbers distinctively. I tried using log numbers, but because there are zeros, I am not able to do that.
What is the best way to plot this data on a single graph and see clear difference between values of B & C against values of A?
I am trying to find a pattern here, as shown in the example where if A <0 C values are high and if A >0 B values are high.

If you do not need the columns to share a common scale, you could consider using two axes, one for column "B" and one for column "C" using twinx().  This would let you control the scale of each independently and make the differences within each column more visible.  For example:
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(df.A, df.C, color = "tab:orange")
ax1.set_xlabel("A")
ax1.set_ylabel("C")

ax2.plot(df.A, df.B, color = "tab:blue") 
ax2.set_ylabel("B")

